# Python: sorting by increasing order

Tags: python, list

I am trying to write a program that, given a list, would sort out the elements in increasing mathematical order. For instance, if the input is [2,4,3,1,5], the output would be [1,2,3,4,5]. My code is:

```
def trival(liste):
   i=0
   l=len(liste)
   while i+1<=l-1:
       a=liste[i]
       b=liste[i+1]
       if a>b:
           a,b=b,a
       print (liste)
       i=i+1
```

However, in the output I receive:

```
[2, 4, 3, 5, 1]
[2, 4, 3, 5, 1]
[2, 4, 3, 5, 1]
[2, 4, 3, 5, 1]
```

So apparently it's wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which sorting algorithm you are using to acheive this ?

Comment: @Tanveer Alam I'm not sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
if a>b:
    a, b = b, a
```

This won't swap the elements, just the local names. You have to reassign the elements in the list:

```
liste[i] = a
liste[i+1] = b
```

Or just work with the values in the list, and not use `a` and `b`. You could also use a `for` loop instead of your while loop, making your code:

```
def trival(liste):
    for i in range(len(liste) - 1):
        if liste[i] > liste[i+1]:
            liste[i], liste[i+1] = liste[i+1], liste[i]
        print(liste)
```

This produces the output of:

```
[2, 4, 3, 1, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 1, 5]
[2, 3, 1, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 1, 4, 5]
```

If you are implementing bubble sort, you will need to iterate until there are no more swaps, so you could use a variable to track that:

```
def trival(liste):
    sorted = False
    while not sorted:
        sorted = True
        for i in range(len(liste) - 1):
            if liste[i] > liste[i+1]:
                liste[i], liste[i+1] = liste[i+1], liste[i]
                sorted = False
            print(liste)
    return liste
```

Which produces the correct result of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. Note that you may want to copy the list, and return the sorted copy, instead of an in-place sort.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are doing here... What is the interest of the 'sorted' variable? I just run your last code through shell, it doesn't give me the good result, but prints the original list about 25 times (I gave 6 elements). Thank you for the long answer though!

Comment: The sorted variable is used to check if there were any swaps during the last "round". If it remains True though out the "round", the list is sorted. Was the list sorted by the end, though? If you want to remove the printed lines, just remove the `print(liste)` line.

Comment: Yes sorry my bad! I didn't notice that it was shifting elements one by one, it actually did arrive to the good result. Is there a way to only view the last result though? Or will this type of code always show the entire process?

Comment: Just remove the `print(liste)`, and do `print(trival(your_list))`?

Answer (score 2):

The following statement does not affect the list. It just swap value of `a`, `b`.

```
a, b = b, a
```

You need to use list item assignment to swap list items:

```
liste[i], liste[i+1] = liste[i+1], liste[i]
```

---

```
>>> liste = [5, 4, 3]
>>> i = 0
>>> a = liste[i]
>>> b = liste[i+1]
>>> a, b = b, a
>>> a   # a, b value changed
4
>>> b
5
>>> liste  # but not for the list.
[5, 4, 3]

>>> liste[i], liste[i+1] = liste[i+1], liste[i]
>>> liste
[4, 5, 3]
```

---

BTW, if you are implementing bubble sort, you need to iterate more (until no swaps occur)

Comment: If it's a bubble sort, you need to iterate only until no swaps occur.

Comment: @martineau, You're right. I updated the answer accordingly. Thank you for pointing that.

Comment: Just a nit, no big deal. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are only doing one pass on your list, so you are only ordering neighbouring elements. Also you need to do:

```
liste[i], liste[i+1] = liste[i+1], liste[i]
```

instead of:

```
a, b = b, a
```

if you really want to change your list. I think this is what you want to do:

```
def trival(liste):
   for j in range(len(liste)-1, 0 ,-1):
        for i in range(j):
            if liste[i]>liste[i+1]:
                liste[i+1],liste[i]=liste[i],liste[i+1]
        print (liste)

>>> trival([2,4,3,1,5])
[2, 3, 1, 4, 5]
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the items back to their respective index.

After the swap, `if a>b: ...` add the following code:

```
liste[i] = a
liste[i+1] = b
```

As the code stands you extract the elements at i and i+1 storing them in separate variables. However a and b doesn't "know" that they belong to the list. They are just values.